# converting data format (Feb 01 2021 10:53:00am KST => 2021-02-01 10:53:00am)

Tags: javascript, types

I need to filter datas by it's dates.
In order to do that I have to convert date to Number.
but I am getting this NaN error.

How can I convert

```
Feb 01 2021 10:53:00am KST
```

into

```
2021-02-01 10:53:00
```

or Is there any way to convert

```
Feb 01 2021 10:53:00am KST
```

to Number directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look at [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#non-standard_date_strings)

This one parses in Chrome `"Feb 01 2021 10:53:00"`

```js
const d = new Date("Feb 01 2021 10:53:00")
console.log(d)
```

So let's try more specific

```js
// We want YYYY-MO-DDTHH:MM:SS.MSC+hh:mm
const months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
const pad = num => ("0"+num).slice(-2);

const dString = "Feb 01 2021 10:53:00am KST"; // assuming mmm dd yyyy hh:mm:ssxx KST where xx is am or pm

let [mmm,dd,yyyy,tString,tz] = dString.split(" ");

let  [_,hh,mm,ss,ampm] = tString.match(/(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})(am|pm)/)

hh = pad(+hh + (ampm==="pm" ? 12 : 0));

const month = pad(months.indexOf(mmm)+1)

const newDString = `${yyyy}-${month}-${dd}T${hh}:${mm}:${ss}.000-09:00`
const date = new Date(newDString)
console.log(newDString,date)
```